# How can I keep my app running when the focus is moved to another app or when the user presses the home button?

Tags: android, home-button

I have read other posts that suggest that I use a service but I am not sure that it will do what I need it to.  I am trying to create an alarm app but once the user presses the home button, the alarm will never go off.  Is there a way to keep my app running when the home button is pressed?

Comment: Why not use the AlarmManager to wake your app when it needs to be running rather than always be running?

Answer (score 2):

You should implement Service running in background (read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) manual) or use an AlarmManager as suggested by [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/307990/greg-giacovelli) (that is better solution)